# Generate C# functions from C++

Tags: c#, c++, reflection, code-generation, converters

I need to generate C# code out from c++ code.

I only need to extract classes and functions and put in notimplementedexception. Example of what I want below:

c++:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        private:
        TestMethodA();

        public:
        TestMethodB(int i);
    }
}
```

to c#

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        private void TestMethodA()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException()
        }

        public bool TestMethodB(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any tools available for generation of this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this C++ (unmanaged), or C++/CLI (.NET)?

Comment: t4 is a pretty nice code generation tool. I assume you will do the parsing and stuff on your own?

Comment: @TimS. C++/CLI (.NET)

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk I guess it's pretty simple, but I can always go through the generated code after and fix the errors. It could just be a start on the porting by using a tool

Comment: Since it's .NET, you should be able to decompile into C# using http://ilspy.net/ - that could be a good starting point.